# Send Facebook user ID as URL parameter

Tags: facebook, analytics, userid, user-identification

Do you know if it's possible to grab FB user ID and pass as a URL parameter? It doesn't seem (and understandably so) like it is one of the dynamic parameters.
https://www.facebook.com/business/help/1016122818401732

(I know it's a far shot, but there are so many brilliant people on stack...)

Cheers,
Florian

Comment: Are you trying to achieve a federated user sign-in or so? I could not get the context you are going to use it.

Comment: Fair point. This is for tracking purposes: we're trying to build a keychain of user IDs for machine learning and possibly retargeting.

Comment: i am not sure if that´s allowed...do all users know about what you want to do with their IDs? either way, you cannot get a user ID without authorizing a user.

Comment: @luschn you're right authorisation would be required. thx